# Do .Net versions have to match between web service and web site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services

I have an existing website that is currently using .Net 3.5 and must stay that way because of our sharepoint integration. I need to write a web service/web api that the website will interact with (a method to send an email, for example). I also need to write a windows service that is going to do the same thing. The windows service will probably be .Net 4.5.

What framework should I use for the web service/web api so both environments can interact with it the best?

Comment: Is your WebAPI going to use dlls from Web site, or do you have to call WebAPI from website ?

Comment: What ever is deemed best practice in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very nature of web services, soap or rest, is that they are platform agnostic. This also applies to .net versions, you can have whatever version at the server and another version at the client and this surely will work.

Comment: WCF Service probably the best way to go?

Comment: WCF = SOAP, WebAPI = REST, it is up to you to decide. There are pros and cons for both.

Comment: I would like the least amount of configuration on the client end. Reading up on REST it talks a lot about CRUD. I don't need that. I need two methods SendBulkEmail(...) and SendSingleEmail(...). Is REST a good fit?

Comment: REST is not CRUD, CRUD can be implemented with REST and SOAP. The choice between rest and soap is subjective.